# About MigrateAnonymous Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have successfully implemented a custom profile that inherits ProfileBase class, to my web "application". The issue is that the 'Anonymous Profile' is turned ON.

As per the MSDN >> MigrateAnonymous << Event is fired moment the anonymous user logs in to the we application.

My Question ->

Where is the coding for the Event is done. In which file/class (sorry, I've been learning ASP.NET on my own so not fluent with lingo)

P.S. I've googled about it and check MSDN << maybe i missed something or i need your assistance.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks John, will keep in mind.